# How to search for two values in a range and show another value?

Tags: excel

I've done a search but can't really find an answer that works for me.

I have a spreadsheet with all our product codes exported from MYOB.

What i want to do, is have separate worksheets for each product category.

So in Sheet1 is all my data, product codes, descriptions costs etc
I then have a worksheet called Pipe List. In pipe list i want to show all products from Sheet1 that contact the value 5-1710 and 5-1711 in column N

I'll then repeat this for each product category. I'd rather have each group separated than using the filter tool.

This sheet then feeds back into other Excel files that use drop downs.

Comment: A brute force approach could be to sort all your products in ascending order, then get a total count for each product type, use the number of product type 1 to copy that many rows on to the first sheet type 1 , then the count of number of type 2 etc... I do this for students in different classes to split a long list into 5 separate classes.. A vba code may be a cleaner way though, but I have not tried that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One is with Power Query. Use Power Query (a.k.a. Get & Transform) to load the data from the first sheet, filter to show only the data for one product group and load into sheet 2. Create a query for each product group and let it save into different sheets.

Then, when you get a new MYOB export, copy that into the first sheet and use Data > Refresh All to refresh all the queries in all the sheet with one button click.

Another option is to use pivot tables. One pivot table on each sheet. Refresh when the data in sheet 1 is changed.

Formulas are also an option but inferior, since you don't know how many rows of formulas you will need and you will have to pre-fill the formula down unnecessarily. This will also make it harder to use the result in data validation dropdowns.

Comment: great idea about the pivots thanks i didnt even think to do that!